# Special character not encoded properly during asmx webrequest

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, web-services

Below is the webmethod in asmx that get the request xml

```
 <WebMethod>
Public Function SubmitOrder(SubmitOrderRequest As SubmitOrderRequest) As SubmitOrderResponse  Implements IIHybrisOrderImportServiceSoapBinding.SubmitOrder
Dim inputserilize As New XmlSerializer(SubmitOrderRequest.GetType)

    Dim strwriters = New StringWriter
    inputserilize.Serialize(strwriters, SubmitOrderRequest)
    WriteToFile("Input XML: " & strwriters.ToString & vbCrLf)
```

The XML request is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
<ns2:SubmitOrderRequest xmlns:ns2="http://cos.ws.sideup.reply.eu/SubmitOrderRequest">
        <Orders>
        <Order>
            <Action>CREATE</Action>
   <BillingAddress>
    <BillingAddress1>Paulñ Pogbaà</BillingAddress1>
```

I am expecting the above XML to be displayed by the asmx with the BillingAddress1 value  as seen above but what i get is as seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<SubmitOrderRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Orders>
    <Order>
      <Action>CREATE</Action>
      <BillingAddress>
        <BillingAddress1>Paul?? Pogba??</BillingAddress1>
```

How can i get the those special characters to be displayed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice the encoding got changed from `UTF-8` to `iso-8859-1`

You need to set the encoding in the `StringWriter`, unfortunately it doesn't support setting encoding straight-forwardly. So create your own `StringWriter` by inheriting from `StringWriter`.

```
Public Class MyStringWriter
    Inherits StringWriter

    Public Overrides Property Encoding As Encoding
        Get
            Return Encoding.UTF8
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Then use in your code:

```
Dim inputserilize As New XmlSerializer(SubmitOrderRequest.GetType)

Dim strwriters = New MyStringWriter
inputserilize.Serialize(strwriters, SubmitOrderRequest)
WriteToFile("Input XML: " & strwriters.ToString & vbCrLf)

Dim inputserilize As New XmlSerializer(SubmitOrderRequest.GetType)

Dim strwriters = New StringWriter
inputserilize.Serialize(strwriters, SubmitOrderRequest)
WriteToFile("Input XML: " & strwriters.ToString & vbCrLf)
```